# Find the line number of a empty line from a certain line using python

Tags: python

I have a file which contains the stack trace. My idea here is to search for a certain word in that file, and if found, get the contents from that line to the next empty line. Below is my code -

```
tdfilename = r"C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\dummystacktrace"
tdf = open(tdfilename)
for num, l in enumerate(tdf, 1):
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE" in l:
        runnable += 1
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)" in l:
        objmonitorwaiting += 1
        linenum = num
tdf.close()
```

I am able to get the line number (`linenum`) of the string i found, here the string i am searching for is `java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)` But how do i get the line number of the next empty line from that point (`linenum`) i.e. line 2 to line 10 or 111 and save all the details into a variable.

Dummy Stack Trace -

```
"Agent Execution" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000074563546f83c4c28000 nid=0x66760e in Object.wait() [0x00007f834737776cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000800567670b280> (a com.wily.util.adt.BlockingQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.wily.util.adt.BlockingQueue.interruptableDequeue(BlockingQueue.java:123)
    - locked <0x00000000800567670b280> (a com.wily.util.adt.BlockingQueue)
    at com.wily.util.task.AsynchExecutionQueue.doTask(AsynchExecutionQueue.java:200)
    at com.wily.util.task.ATask$CoreTask.run(ATask.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread Monitor Heartbeat Heartbeat" #6 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000342523454c4c26000 nid=0x2260d in Object.wait() [0x00007f8789078903777d0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000008057567004b38> (a com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat.waitForBehaviorIfEmpty(IntervalHeartbeat.java:570)
    - locked <0x000000008057567004b38> (a com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat)
    at com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat.access$1(IntervalHeartbeat.java:562)
    at com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat$HeartbeatRunnable.run(IntervalHeartbeat.java:667)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Agent Heartbeat" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f834567465c4c24000 nid=0x60c sleeping[0x00007f8757563778d1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.wily.util.heartbeat.IntervalHeartbeat$HeartbeatRunnable.run(IntervalHeartbeat.java:673)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Kindly clarify.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are **actually trying to achieve**, rather than how you want to do it. See [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the inherent boolean nature of a string in python.

```
tdfilename = r"C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\dummystacktrace"
tdf = open(tdfilename)
endnum = None
for num, l in enumerate(tdf, 1):
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE" in l:
        runnable += 1
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)" in l:
        objmonitorwaiting += 1
        linenum = num
    if not l.strip() and num > linenum and endnum is None:
        end_num = num
tdf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just save them off as you go. No need to track line numbers.

The `appending` flag keeps track of whether you're in a segment you need to save. If you need to grab multiple sections per file, the structure might get more complicated, but the basic idea is the same.

```
tdfilename = r"C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\dummystacktrace"
tdf = open(tdfilename)
appending = False
lines = []
for num, l in enumerate(tdf, 1):
    if appending:
        if l.strip():
            lines.append(l)
        else:
            appending = False
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE" in l:
        runnable += 1
    if "java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)" in l:
        objmonitorwaiting += 1
        linenum = num
        appending = True
tdf.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `appending` be `False` in beginning.

Comment: Thanks @RahulChawla

Comment: how will i be able to capture the data from line 1 to line 11 using         `appending = True`. sorry i actually didn't get it

Comment: @sdgd It's set up so that `appending` is True whenever you are between the object monitor line and the first empty line. Then you use it to save off whatever lines you need as you go.